# Can anybody explain in precise why serial version id is static in java

Tags: java, serialization, static

Whenever we come across serialization our minds jump  into serial version id.
    As per the serialization api we cannot make object as static if we want to serialize it then, how come we can make "*serialiversionid*" as static.

Signature is as follows

> private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

I got following information after googling .

> During deserialization, Object needs to be created from the data. If
>   there's no way to check whether object is deserializable, there's no
>   way to get the Object members.

Any other information would be good with an example

Answer (score 2):

On de-serialization, Java looks into the stream to see which type and serialVersionUID come next. Based on this, the *static* class definition is looked up in the class loaders to create an object that will then receive the data read from the stream.

Now, to make sure that the attributes in the stream match the attributes of that object that's about to be filled, Java checks the serialVersionUID. This needs to be *static*, as the class definition in the classloader is static, too. You can't have morphing classes with changing signatures (members) in the same classloader in Java.

Checking the serialVersionUID is a safety measure that prevents incomplete object initialization, i.e. when the stream does not contain member data (written with an earlier code version), but the current signature (and object contract) calls for the additional member to be set to something. You *may* allow such incomplete (not de-serialized members) by not changing the serialVersionUID, but if you want to make sure that no members are left out on de-serialization, you need to bump/change the serialVersionUID.

(Maybe a good hiring interview question. Not sure if I qualified, though :-) )

Comment: Thanks . Thats very useful explanation.You are qualified in interview if I would have taken yours  :)

Comment: There is rarely if ever any point to changing the `serialVersionUID`. All that accomplishes is breaking Serialization completely, instead of partially as would happen if you modified the fields enough without changing the `serialVersionUID`. It is not to be thought of as a class version number to be incremented, despite its unfortunate name.

Answer (score 1):

It is static because it is a property of the class, not of the object. Simple as that.

If you're wondering how it gets serialized with the object, it doesn't: it is sent as part of the object's class metadata, which is only sent once per connection per class.

Comment: Thanks for the info